# Loop through drop down list and save the workbook as a new file

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hi I have the following code which loops through dropdown selections and saves each result as a new workbook based on the named range  in cell G3. I am trying to edit the code so that it saves all the worksheets to the new file instead of just the active one, if anyone could help? thank you

```
Sub myFiles()   
    
Dim wb As Workbook           
Dim ws As Worksheet   
Dim nwb As Workbook      
Dim nws As Worksheet      
Dim rng As Range    
Dim Path As String    
Dim myDate As String       

Set wb = ThisWorkbook     
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Summary")    
Set rng = ws.Range("G3")    

Path = "C:\Users\bradley\Desktop\Sales by Month\"   
 
myDate = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")    
  
For i = 1 To 4    
    rng = ws.Range("J" & i)           
    ws.Copy        
    
    Set nwb = ActiveWorkbook   
    Set nws = nwb.Worksheets("Summary")      

     With nws  
  
         Cells.Copy    
         Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)  
  
     End With    

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False    
     nwb.SaveAs FileName:=Path & rng & " " & myDate & ".xlsx", 
     FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
     nwb.Close    
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True    

Next i    

End Sub
```

Comment: NOTE: It's not `With nws  
         Cells.Copy  ` but rather `With nws  
         .Cells.Copy`

Comment: HI the code above works without any errors, just need to add to it so that all the worksheets are copied

Comment: `wb.Sheets.Copy` will copy all sheets from `wb`

Comment: Hi , The code seems to work with the change suggested, how would I save the workbook as a macro enabled book as one of the sheets contains macros, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the sheets but only create a workbook on the first one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub myFiles()
       
    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\bradley\Desktop\Sales by Month\"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, nwb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim myDate As String, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim filename As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("G3")
    myDate = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY")
      
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 4
        rng.Value2 = ws.Range("J" & i).Value2
        
        ' copy all sheets
        For j = 1 To wb.Sheets.Count
            If j = 1 Then
                wb.Sheets(j).Copy
                Set nwb = ActiveWorkbook
            Else
                wb.Sheets(j).Copy after:=nwb.Sheets(j - 1)
            End If

            With nwb.Sheets(j)
                .UsedRange.Value2 = .UsedRange.Value2
            End With
        Next
        
        ' save workbook
        filename = FOLDER & rng.Value2 & " " & myDate & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        nwb.SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
        nwb.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```